# Redirection in cakephp 2.7.5 not working properly

Tags: php, cakephp

Recently I install `cakephp 2.7.5` in my system and I develop admin for backend.I face some problem in it,when I add `faq` in admin section it will not shown in `faq` section but when I refresh page it will shown the redirection code is here:-

`$this->redirect(array('controller'=>'Firmcategory','action' => 'index'));`

The same problem is also for delete section when I delete some item for that I set code delete and redirect back to index page of admin it will redirect but change not shown when I refresh page it will shown flash message and delete

Please help what I missed in my installation.

Comment: `Firmcategory` needs to be `FirmCategories` and your controller name must be `FirmCategoriesController`

Comment: Anant's solution is correct, and regarding delete, please share your code.

Comment: @prats1411 this is my code for delete $this->FirmCategory->id = $id;
        $this->FirmCategory->delete();
  $this->Session->setFlash(__('Successfully Deleted'),'default',array('class' => 'alert alert-success'), 'alert');
  $this->redirect(array('controller'=>'FirmCategories','action' => 'index'));

Comment: it has deleted from database but shown on page when i refresh page then it will show flash message and delete

Answer (score 0):

Could you prove this?

return $this->redirect(array('controller'=>'FirmCategories','action' => 'index'));